# Reading cell styles along with data-Excel sheet reading using apache POI

Tags: excel, grails, import, apache-poi

folks, I am able to read the excel sheet using apache POI in grails
using this I am inserting the cell values into different tables of mysql,
My problem is, I am not able to get the cell style like, bold or italic etc along with the data.
generally text area will automatically give the style of text while inserting into database. 
I need to insert the data along with its style from each cell, please help me in solving it.

Comment: How are you expecting to be able to store this style information in your database? Especially given that one string in excel can have different styles applied to different parts of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getCellStyle()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getCellStyle%28%29)

This should get the CellStyle from the cell, which then you can use to get the information you want.

Comment: Thank you xxpor, the getCellStyle() will return the object, after this only i got confused what to do/how to get the style using this object. Like, the way how can i get the style value using this object. can you please give me an example of it

Comment: There's many elements to style, what element are you looking for?

Comment: Like, suppose if i enter data inside cell with the bold style or italic i should be able to insert the same style attribute into database so that when i retrieve the same data from other front end i should be able to get the same style.

Comment: I'm not sure how practical that is. If you look at the cell style documentation, you can see how many things there are. Is it bossible to store the binary blob of the excel file into the db?

Comment: I'll look into it again, Btw, i tried blob also, but in my appication i cant use blob as i'm performing many string operations at the front end it cause a problem